# Internal page links do not work in iOS Safari browser

Tags: html, css

I am new at programming so forgive me if this post is done incorrectly. I am currently working on the Product Landing Page project for Free Code Camp's Responsive Web Design certificate. One of the requirements is to add anchor links to a fixed navbar. The links are supposed to jump to points within the same page.
The links work correctly on desktop, but when I click the links in the Safari browser on my iPhone XS, they do not work.

I haven't found any solutions online to this- people have described having difficulty with links to other pages in Safari, but no one has shown a solution to links within the same page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ebf4ed;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.page-title {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header-img {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 550px) {
  #header {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: table;
  }
  .page-title {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #home-link {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #header-img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="page-title">
    <a href="#header">
      <h1 class="link" id="home-link">Sequoia Advisors</h1>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj3kejb1m10d685/mangrove1.png?raw=1" alt="Sequoia company logo" id="header-img">
  </div>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#about-title">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#pricing-container">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#form-container">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The anchor links link to the id of the title for each section. I need them to be responsive in mobile- not sure if this is a Safari problem or a mobile problem in general.

Comment: Your HTMl code doesn't contain the elements which have the IDs the menu links refer to...

Comment: @Elizabeth If my answer helped you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  it or give it a vote (when you reach 15 rep). In order to see the accept 'check' mark, you just hover under the arrows to the left of the answer (no min rep required to do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to illustrate what others have commented, that your code is missing the code to give the desired outcome, I added internal anchor links for your form and about sections. The content added is dummy content, and deliberately oversized so you could see the 'jump-to' effect. I also adjusted the position in your header css from fixed to relative, so that the sections would display correctly. (I don't think it's a Safari issue, just a matter of missing content, and that you would experience the same problem on any browser)

Hope this helps

```css
body {
  background-color: #ebf4ed;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.page-title {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header-img {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#aboutus,
#form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: table;
  }
  .page-title {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #home-link {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #header-img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #content{top:200px} h2 a{margin-top:200px;}
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="page-title">
    <a href="#header">
      <h1 class="link" id="home-link">Sequoia Advisors</h1>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj3kejb1m10d685/mangrove1.png?raw=1" alt="Sequoia company logo" id="header-img">
  </div>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#about-title">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#pricing-container">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#form-container">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="content">

  <div id="aboutus">
    <h2>About <a name="about-title"></a></h2>
    <p>Hi, we're Stackoverflow users!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="form">
    <h2>MyForm <a name="form-container"></a></h2>
    <p>form goes here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a lot more code below the header html that I put in my post but I just didn't think it would be relevant to answering my question. The problem with your solution is that it takes away the position: fixed, which is a requirement for the project. I will definitely try adding the anchor link to the section I am trying to link to though

Comment: @Elizabeth I adjusted the position fixed as a quick fix to display the sections in the snippet, you can change it back, but you will have to ensure that it doesn't affect the code for other divs or if it does you can add additional CSS. Welcome to stackoverflow btw!

Comment: @Elizabeth I changed the position:relative; back to position:fixed; in your header, as you requested. However you can see the issue with using position:fixed with this code. I widened the media-query to max-width:700px, but only so that the media effect could be seen in the stack snippet, you can adjust this back once you've looked at it..

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have the elements that you try to navigate with `#about-title` `#pricing-container` `#form-container` elements. They must exist in your HTML in order to provide the correct navigation.